# Displaying one hdmi signal for both eyes on one screen VR

Tags: microcontroller, virtual-reality

I am currently working on a DIY VR headset and I have run into a big problem.

My idea was to use an accelerometer and a microcontroller to make a USB computer mouse based on movements. I was going to put a 7 inch LCD screen in a 3D printed enclosure witch also holds the accelerometer.

I was going to connect the micro controller and screen to my PC. This would allow me to somewhat play VR.

Obviously, I would not be able to play games made for real VR headsets like the Oculus or Vibe but I would be able to play nonVR games as long as they were 3D and first person. Every thing seemed great until I got to the problem of displaying the content in VR format.

I figured there would be software to do this but I have only found programs and SDK's for true VR head sets. My idea is to some how to use something like unity to run in the background and capture the screen in real time then use an SDK to duplicate the view and out put it through another port.

Being able to see the game on my monitor while in VR mode is not necessary. I have very little experience with GUI and video output.

Any help would be very appreciated and if you can think of a better way to solve this problem I would love to hear it. I am not sure if this would help but the screen I was planing on using can be [found here:](http://www.waveshare.com/product/7inch-hdmi-lcd-c.htm)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Although your issue sounds quite interesting, you have asked in a manner that makes difficult to help you: you provided an extensive description of context, but provided little details that can help to *reproduce* your problem. What does "problem of split duplicate screens" mean? What's your setup? Best regards.

Comment: Displaying the information is THE problem you have to solve, long before you buy or build or 3d print you have to solve THE problem.  Then coming up with headsets and other things are the easy part, you can bang out several prototypes.  If you have little experience with video output, start there, then read up on the various solutions, then think which one you might use, and then plan out a prototype.  You have the cart before the horse, run before you walk.

Answer (score 0):

So turning a non-VR game into a VR game that doesn't make you sick will unfortunately take more than mouse/keyboard emulation. (so full disclosure, I am the lead designer of the OSVR software framework and work at Sensics, HMD designers and co-founders of OSVR, but...) I'm not sure if there's a product that will do mirroring/split-screen on an HDMI stream, but FWIW the OSVR HDK 1.x (just the 1.x, not the 2!) has an FPGA in it (between the HDMI receiver and the MIPI bridge that drives the display) that enables such a "split-screen" mode: it's not a 3d solution, but for instance I've heard of people plugging in to a first-person-view (FPV) setup on a multirotor drone and using that configuration to just provide a semi-immersive view - obviously they aren't using head tracking, etc. If that's the kind of experience you're looking for, with non-VR applications, then you need to find something that can take HDMI input, and clone and squash it side-by-side, before re-transmitting HDMI. Might be tricky, but then again, I haven't looked for such things.

The other option you have is to make your device a "real HMD" by writing the code (primarily just a plugin for your tracker if there isn't one already - not that an accelerometer on its own won't cut it, you need a gyro too, and probably for ease of use you'd want them in an IMU chip that does decent on-board fusion into a single orientation quaternion - quality, performance, and suitability for VR usage varies widely) and configuration (describing the display) required to use it via OSVR. This is easier than you might think. You'd naturally eventually hit the same issues professional HMD designers hit if you tried to make your device really high performing (optics, minimizing latency in both display and tracking, etc), but it could be a fun hobby project for a person with the right interests. (Shameless, disclaimed plug, because I'm not sure where else you'd get these - http://osvrstore.com has stand-alone optics for purchase that are designed for HMD usage, and generally are actually shipping in commercial HMDs - the alternative I guess would be hacking a Cardboard and using those lenses, though you get a smaller field of view there, which might not be terrible since the resolution of that display is pretty low so if you stick larger FoV optics on it, you'd now make the fewer pixels quite large...)

I am aware of several folks who have done such a DIY HMD (or started with a sort of kit from aliexpress, etc) and gotten them working through OSVR. Then they're effectively indistinguishable to "real VR apps" from commercially-built headsets. (And, there are some VR-adaptation-layer things like Vireio Perception and others that try to turn non-VR apps into VR ones with varying success - some of those support OSVR so they'd support your handmade HMD).

If you do go this route, keep in touch with the OSVR community and let us know what you build - these sorts of hacks are some of the things the framework is designed to promote. The dev mailing list and the OSVR subreddit are probably the best places ATM to reach us.